# Java annotations tutorial

Tags: java, annotations

I am involved with a Java project which uses *annotations*.  Is it possible to develop custom annotations or it is limited to the ones that are already set up by the Java framework?

If there exists any good Java annotations tutorial on the web that will show how to build a custom annotation, can someone please provide me with that link.

I am asking this because I believe this is the best way for me to understand annotations fully.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/ is one.  Yes you can.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/   Took me all of 10 seconds to find.

Comment: It is important to note that some of the tutorial is based on Java 8 - if you use Java 7 some of it won't be applicable.

Comment: Thank you so much for information.  I had a quick search on google and there was lots of information on annotations but at the time of raising this question I hadn't found one that was a good introduction to building my own annotations.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own annotation to satisfy your needs.

**Here a nice tutorial:**

http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2009/12/29/create-your-own-java-customized-annotations/

Here some meta-annotations for the newly created annotation that you might create:

***Meta annotations are actually annotations being used by annotations.***

**- @Target** – specifies the type pf element this annotation is attached to.

```
ElementType.TYPE-can be applied to any element of a class
ElementType.FIELD-can be applied to a field or property
ElementType.METHOD-can be applied to a method level annotation
ElementType.PARAMETER-can be applied to the parameters of a method
ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR-can be applied to constructors
ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE-can be applied to local variables
ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE-indicates that the declared type itself is an annotation type
```

**- @Retention** – specifies the retention level of this annotation.

```
RetentionPolicy.SOURCE—Retained only at the source level and will be ignored by the compiler
RetentionPolicy.CLASS—Retained by the compiler at compile time, but will be ignored by the VM
RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME—Retained by the VM so they can be read only at run-time
```

**- @Documented** – by default annotations are mentioned in java doc, this meta-annotation will make this annotation to be mentioned.

**- @Inherited** – Indicates that the annotation will automatically be inherited

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to build annotations yourself, they're basically special interfaces. Check [Lesson: Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) from the Oracle website for an introduction into building them yourself.

Hint: Finding this link was as simple as searching for "java annotations tutorial" on Google. You can find other ones the same way.

Comment: Thank you so much for information.  I had a quick search on google and there was lots of information on annotations but at the time of raising this question I hadn't found one that was a good introduction to building my own annotations.  Thanks again